# How to use 2 IP addresses on one Postfix server?

Tags: linux, postfix, email-server, hostname

I've a postfix server running on a centOS machine. I added a secondary IP but the emails are always being sent by the 1st IP.

I have A Records:

```
m1.domain.com -> 11.11.11.11
m2.domain.com -> 22.22.22.22
```

And the reverses are:

```
11.11.11.11 -> m1.domain.com
22.22.22.22 -> m2.domain.com
```

If I connect with a simple PHPmailer to m1.domain.com I need to send the email from 11.11.11.11, if I connect to m2.domain.com I need to send the email from 22.22.22.22

I tried to use the `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps` defining 2 different `smtp_bind_address` on master.cf but it does nothing... maybe because I'm using this configuration with postfix + dovecot  + mysql.

https://www.linode.com/docs/email/postfix/email-with-postfix-dovecot-and-mariadb-on-centos-7

Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you add another `MX` record to your DNS?

Comment: I have no MX records created yet, which ones should I put? I don't think it's because of it.

Comment: you need to add both your mail servers. Here, read: http://support.simpledns.com/kb/a44/what-are-mx-records-and-why-do-i-need-this-to-run-an-e-mail-server.aspx

Comment: The problem is sending, not receiving.

Comment: I would say that, if everything is properly configured (can't know untill you post relevant configurations), it's an issue with DNS requests.

Comment: Thanks but it isn't, the problem is that the outgoing IP is being the same all time and I don't know how to solve this.